# Javascript: Map iterate object keys and values

Tags: javascript

Trying to get both key and value using  the following script

```
jsonData = {"jurisdiction":"SCPB - LON","firstName":"David Dynamic"}

var keys   = Object.keys(jsonData).map(function(keys, values) {
    logInfo(jsonData[keys], jsonData[values]);              
});
```

**returns just the values**:

```
2022-08-30 18:29:49 David Dynamic undefined
2022-08-30 18:29:49 SCPB - LON undefined
```

How can I get both? the js engine is `spiderMonkey 1.8`

Comment: `Object.entries`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Object.keys(jsonData).forEach(function(key) {
    logInfo(key, jsonData[key]);              
});
```

[Object.keys documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Or as suggested by Kondrak Linkowski:

```
Object.entries(jsonData).forEach(([key, value]) => logInfo(key, value))
```

Answer (score 2):

You likely want to use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the keys and values of the object.

If you want to do it with `Object.keys`, as in your example, you can modify it like this: (logging the key, and the value at this key)

```js
const jsonData = {
 foo: 'bar',
 fizz: 'fuzz',
}
const logInfo = console.log

var keys = Object.keys(jsonData).map(function(key) {
    logInfo(key, jsonData[key]);              
});
```